# Azure IoT Hub Java SDK, connecting X.509 Devices multiplexed over single AMQP Connection

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk, azure-iot-hub-device-management

I have auto provisioned a bunch of IoT devices via Azure IoT DPS. The devices are registered at my IoT hub. All devices have an X.509 certificate authentication.

What I now want to do is to send messages to the devices. All certificates are available and I can connect with the DeviceClient to the device at the hub. This is the method of the Azure IoT Java SDK I am using:

```
public static DeviceClient createFromSecurityProvider(String uri, String deviceId, SecurityProvider securityProvider, IotHubClientProtocol protocol) throws URISyntaxException, IOException
```

It takes ***SecurityProviderX509Cert*** as parameter.

However, each DeviceClient has its own physical connection. What I want is to use AMQP multiplexing by using this constructor:

```
public DeviceClient(String connString, TransportClient transportClient) throws URISyntaxException
```

This doesn't work with X.509 devices. In the connection string I've used the shared access key from my shared access policy from the hub but got an exception:

***Unauthorized: Device 'xxx' at IotHub 'yyy' does not have PrimaryKey or SecondaryKey***

I assume that will only work if I register the device with symmetric keys. However, those devices cannot be enrolled automatically via Azure DPS. I can only enroll devices with X.509 or TPM.

So how do I get the trick to connect multiple X.509 devices over a single AMQPS connection?

Comment: What is the authentication type of the device in the IoT devices, X.509 Self-signed or X.509 CA signed?

Comment: X.509 self signed

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Azure IoT Hub SDK for Java does not support multiplexing for X.509 devices.

You can post a requirement for this feature on github(https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-java/issues).

Comment: Done! Thank you!